# How to use autohosts for Apache?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration, apache2

I read an [article](http://everzet.com/post/33810120695/autohosts-for-symfony-projects-on-mac) about autohosts at Apache webserver. I think it's awesome solution, but is it working for Ubuntu? Could not find any info how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working independent of the OS:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html